# Joining rows with columns to create vertical table

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to join 2 data frames to create a vertical table of the data. Here is some sample data:

```
people <- data.frame(person = c("John","David","Peter"), company = c("A", "B", "C"))
grades <- data.frame(person1=c(10, 40, 50, 60), person2=c(60,70,80, 100), person3=c(33,44,55, 75))
```

NOTE: The order of the columns in `grades` is the same as the order of the `person` column in the `people` data frame.

I would like to get a data frame like the following but can't think of how to get there. Would prefer a solution using base R (am using an older version of R so some packages don't work for me):

```
person | company | grade
-------------------------
 John  |    A    | 10
 John  |    A    | 40
 John  |    A    | 50
 John  |    A    | 60
David  |    B    | 60
David  |    B    | 70
David  |    B    | 80
David  |    B    | 100
Peter  |    C    | 33
Peter  |    C    | 44
Peter  |    C    | 55
Peter  |    C    | 75
```

Comment: Perhaps `gather(grades) %>% separate(key, into = c('person', 'grades'))`  Note the names are not the same in both datasets

Comment: that is on purpose... I can't use the names of the grades list as they seem to be inconsistent. Would need to use index.

Comment: Ok, but `pj` anif there is `pt` it would create issues

Comment: If the third name `pj` can be changed to match the pattern `gather(grades) %>% separate(key, into = c('person', 'grades')) %>% select(-grades) %>% regex_left_join(people, by = "person", ignore_case = TRUE)`

Comment: if is the same order change names of grades with person column gather and do a simple join

Comment: @akrun - updated the question. This closely resembles the data I'm looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We change the column names of 'grades' with 'person' column from 'people', `gather` into 'long' format and then do a `left_join`

```
library(tidyverse)
setNames(grades, people$person) %>% 
     gather(person, grade) %>% 
    left_join(people)
#   person grade company
#1    John    10       A
#2    John    40       A
#3    John    50       A
#4    John    60       A
#5   David    60       B
#6   David    70       B
#7   David    80       B
#8   David   100       B
#9   Peter    33       C
#10  Peter    44       C
#11  Peter    55       C
#12  Peter    75       C
```

---

Or using `base R` with `merge`

```
merge(stack(setNames(grades, people$person)), 
      people, all.x = TRUE, by.x = 'ind', by.y = 'person')
```

Comment: love the simplicity in the base R approach

Comment: A variant instead of using `setNames` would be: `colnames(grades) <- people$person
merge(stack(grades), people, by.x = "ind", by.y = "person")`

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `cbind` would be

```
idx <- rep(seq_along(people$person), each = dim(grades)[1])
cbind(people[idx,], stack(unlist(grades))["values"])
```

Result

```
#    person company values
#1     John       A     10
#1.1   John       A     40
#1.2   John       A     50
#1.3   John       A     60
#2    David       B     60
#2.1  David       B     70
#2.2  David       B     80
#2.3  David       B    100
#3    Peter       C     33
#3.1  Peter       C     44
#3.2  Peter       C     55
#3.3  Peter       C     75
```

---

Use `unlist` and `stack` on `grades` to get

```
stack(unlist(grades))
   values          ind
1      10 john_grades1
2      40 john_grades2
3      50 john_grades3
4      60 john_grades4
5      60       david1
6      70       david2
7      80       david3
8     100       david4
9      33          pj1
10     44          pj2
11     55          pj3
12     75          pj4
```

Since "The order of the columns in grades is the same as the order of the person column in the people data frame." we can use `cbind` next, after we expanded `people` to have the correct number of rows.

```
(idx <- rep(seq_along(people$person), each = dim(grades)[1]))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

---

Another option, probably a little faster would be

```
cbind(people[idx,], data.frame(grade = unlist(grades, use.names = FALSE)))
```